# Running api on ESP32 with micropython

Tags: python, api, fastapi, esp32, micropython

I am making my home smart using esp32 and micropython. I have a Django project running on a server I have on my LAN and I want to send commands to my esp32 wirelessly through it. Maybe something like running a uvicorn server and a fastapi app and then sending messages to the uvicorn server endpoints and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use either [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [django-websocket](https://pypi.org/project/django-websocket/)

But I'm not sure if `websockets` package is ported for micropython, so you might need to use plain socket

*Or* try something completely different. Physically connect the server and esp32 together (I have absolutely no idea about it)

My recommendation is the first option

Comment: i had to use socket and it worked